# MySQL - Best method of saving and loading items

Tags: mysql, loading, save

So on my older work, I had always used the 'text' data type to store items, like so:

```
0=4151:54;1=995:5000;2=521:1;
```

So basically: `slot=item:amount;`

I've been looking into finding the best ways of storing information in a sql database, and everywhere i go, it says that using text is a big performance hit.

I was thinking of doing something else, like having a table with the following columns:

```
id, owner_id, slot_id, item_id, amount
```

Where as now i can just insert a row for each item a character allocates. But i have no clue how to save them, since the slot's item can change, etc. A character has 28 inventory slots, and 500 bank slots, should i insert them all at registration? or is there a smarter way to save the items

Comment: A bit more explanation please. I can almost grasp what you mean, but you should say what you mean by 'slot', 'character' and 'bank' because the usage is a little *strange*. This also seems to be a question about database structure, rather than 'saving and loading'.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't explain well enough.

Well the slot is the entry point at which the item is located in the inventory / bank. Since the slots aren't sorted, the id's could be be 1, 2, 3, then skip to 8 etc.

character being the owner of the item(s), and bank being the item container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes use that structure. Using text to store relational data defeats the purpose of a relational database.

I don't see what you mean by insert them all at registration. Can you not insert them as you need to?

**Edit**

Based on your previous comment I would recommend only inserting a slot as it is needed (if I understand your problem). It may be an idea to keep the ID of the slot in the application, if need be.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, and that the slot's item can change, then you want to further abstract the mapping between item_id and the item:

```
entry_tbl.item_id->item_rel_realitems_tbl.real_id->items_tbl
```

This way, all entries with an itemid point to a table that maps those ids to a mutable item. When you UPDATE an item in 'items_tbl' then the mapping automatically updates the entry_tbl.

Another JOIN is needed however. I would also use **stored procedures** in any case to abstract the mechanism from semantics.

I am not sure I understand the wording of your question however.